# Изменение выводимого значения afc в wordpess

Tags: wordpress, acf, хук

в вордпрессе используются произвольные поля(acf). Клиент хочет домножить значение одного из полей на некий коэффициент, но так, чтобы значение менялось только в выводе (чтобы у самой записи значение поля не менялось (имею ввиду значение, записанное в бд) )
Вот вопрос - возможно ли изменить значение при помощи хуков в functions.php, например, чтобы не менять несколько шаблонов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте фильтр `acf/load_field`:

```
/**
 * Filter field.
 *
 * @param array $field Field to filter.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function acf_load_field_filter( $field ) {
    if ( 'my_field_name' === $field['name'] ) {
        $field['value'] = $field['value'] * 2;
    }

    return $field;
}

add_filter( 'acf/load_field', 'acf_load_field_filter' );
```